# Removing duplicate objects in a list (C#)

Tags: c#, linq, list, duplicates

So I understand how to remove duplicates in a list when it comes to strings and int, etc by using `Distinct()` from Linq. But how do you remove duplicates based on a specific attribute of an object?

For example, I have a `TimeMetric` class. This `TimeMetric` class has two attributes: `MetricText` and `MetricTime`. I have a list of `TimeMetrics` called `MetricList`. I want to remove any duplicates `TimeMetric` with the same `MetricText` attribute. The `TimeMetric` value can be the same but if any `TimeMetric` has the same `MetricText`, it must be unduplicated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use the second overload of `Distinct` that takes an [`IEqualityComparer<TimeMetric>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) instance as a second parameter. Define a comparer like this:

```
class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<TimeMetric>
{
    public bool Equals(TimeMetric x, TimeMetric y)
    {
        return x.MetricText.Equals(y.MetricText);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(TimeMetric obj)
    {
        return obj.MetricText.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

**Important note:** The above code does not check for the case where the `MetricText` property is `null` (and it sounds like it could be, since it's most probably a `string`). You should do that and return `0` from `GetHashCode` if `MetricText` is `null`. On the other hand, if the type of `MetricText` is a value type, you don't need to perform any modification.

And then:

```
var list = new List<TimeMetric> { ... };
var unique = list.Distinct(new MyComparer());
```

Answer (score 15):

Use linq:

```
var list = list 
    .GroupBy(i => i.MetricText)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();
```

Or pass in a comparer that uses the property:

```cs
public class mtCompare : IEqualityComparer<TimeMetric>
{
  public bool Equals(TimeMetric x, TimeMetric y)
  {
    return Equals(x.MetricText, y.MetricText);
  }

  public int GetHashCode(TimeMetric obj)
  {
    return obj.MetricText.GetHashCode();
  }
}

....

list.Distinct(new mtCompare());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Distinct overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) with an [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx).

Your equals method for your IEqualityComparer implementation would look like this:

```
bool Equals(TimeMetric x, TimeMetric y)
{
  return x.MetricText.Equals(y.MetricText);
}
```

Comment: This is not correct and will only work as it should if `MetricText` is of type `string` (or another type that overrides `operator ==`). `Equals` should be used instead.

Comment: I assumed it was a string, which was not a good assumption, and updated the response.